# About definition of $L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty(\Omega))$ and null sets

Tags: functional-analysis

The norm in $L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty(\Omega))$ is
$$\text{esssup}_{t \in [0,T]}\text{esssup}_{x \in \Omega}|u(t,x)|$$

In the inner essential supremum, can the null set (on which the function fails to be bounded by the essential supremum) depend on $t$ or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can. Let $M$ be the $L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty(\Omega))$ norm of $u$. Then all you know is that for every $t$, there is a null set $N_t\subset \Omega$ such that $|u|\le M$ on $\Omega\setminus N_t$.

The union of $N_t$ over $t$ may well have positive measure. But more relevant is the  set $$N = \{(t,x) \in (0,T)\times \Omega: x\in N_t\}$$
which has zero measure by the Fubini theorem **if** it is measurable. If $N$  fails to be measurable, $u$ may fail to be  in $L^\infty((0,T)\times \Omega)$.